# Iterating through JSON to update only single element

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below JSON. How would I go about iterating through this in pure javascript to update the coordinates only for bCoordinates?

```
    { aCoordinates: { latitude: 22.572646, longitude: 88.36389500000001 },
  bCoordinates: { latitude: 22.572646, longitude: 88.36389500000001 } }
```

Comment: `bCoordinates.latitude = 'value1'` and `bCoordinates.longitude = 'value2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why iterate? Just access it directly:

```js
let data = {
  aCoordinates: {
    latitude: 22.572646,
    longitude: 88.36389500000001
  },
  bCoordinates: {
    latitude: 22.572646,
    longitude: 88.36389500000001
  }
}

data.bCoordinates.latitude = 1
data.bCoordinates.longitude = -1

console.log(data)
```

Comment: That looks like it's working so I'll mark as answered. I'm unable to save the data to my mongoose/mongodb but I suspect that's another issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is being stored in a key-pair object, 
you don't really need to iterate.

```js
// you could use Object Spread Operator if supported by your runtime
const update = (data, id, field, value) => Object
  .assign({}, data, {
    [id]: Object.assign({}, data[id], { [field]: value }),
  })
;

const data =   { 
  aCoordinates: { 
    latitude: 22.572646, 
    longitude: 88.36389500000001,
  },
  bCoordinates: { 
    latitude: 22.572646, 
    longitude: 88.36389500000001,
  },
}

const data2 = update(data, 'bCoordinates', 'longitude', 2.9);

// console.log('data', data);
console.log('data2', data2);
```